# Updating Only Changed Rows Using GridView Control

Tags: asp.net, gridview

what is the best way of updating to db only the changed rows using gridview?

i have a gridview control that has inline editing and when the user edit the row there are two options "Update" or "Cancel" so user might just click update button without really updating the row...

how can i make sure that, user really changed the row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i could not find what i wanted to do so the easiest way of doing this is:

load the data in a object and compare with `Equals` it works fine in my scenario and the only cons is trip to db which is fine in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use it much but are you sure the GridView doesn't handle that automatically if you are using the built in edit functionality. You could try debugging the OnRowUpdated and OnRowUpdating methods to see if they even get called when save is clicked and nothing has been changed. Even if you don't need them just add them so you can put a break point there to see if they get triggered.

Comment: yes i do have onRowUpdating event and when i click it does call but my question is if you capture on that event(OnRowUpdating) which is too late to know what was the orginal vs changed value? agree?

Comment: If my understanding is correct "OnRowUpdating" is before the fact. So if you need to modify the user input before saving to the database you would do that. "OnRowUpdated" is after the fact so if after it saves you want to something based on the new value you could there. Add an onRowUpdated handler and see if it gets called when no information is changed.

Comment: See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowupdating.aspx Also note in the documentation the "NewValues" and "OldValues" which would let you check for a change.

Comment: ok so i debug and in the onRowUpdating event i am getting what i have updated in my case textbox.text value... but what i want is the orginal value.

Comment: Your event args for that method should be GridViewUpdateEventArgs so if you had OnRowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e) then you would could do something like: bool changed=false;
for(int i = 0; i < e.oldValues.count; i++){
 if(e.oldvalues[i].toString() != e.newValues[i].toString()){changed=true;}
}

Comment: See this for the oldValues property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewupdatedeventargs.oldvalues.aspx

Comment: okay so it `e.OldValues.Count` has only 1 --- but it should be more and may be because in my DataKeyNames="id"

Comment: i tried this also but it counts 1 `foreach (System.Collections.DictionaryEntry entry in e.OldValues)
            {
                e.NewValues[entry.Key] = Server.HtmlEncode(entry.Value.ToString());
            }`